# Show refresh button on new Posts

Tags: api, shopify, backend, webhooks

This is my first question on stackoverflow. I am recieving a webhook from shopify on the creation of new order on my private app, I want to show the refresh button on my app(frontend) when I recieve the webhook. I am looking for a best practice to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.